# Хочу сделать так, чтобы вращение останавливалось при столкновении. Или просто сделать импульс вращения

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Выдает предупреждение, что `OnCollisionEnter` нигде не используется

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ImpulseForce : MonoBehaviour 
{


Vector3 impulseMagnitude = new Vector3(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

bool m_oneTime = true;

void Start () 
    {

    }
void FixedUpdate()
    {
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(180, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
    {
    if (collision.gameObject.name=="floor")
        {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
    if (m_oneTime)
        {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(impulseMagnitude, ForceMode.Impulse);
        m_oneTime = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Я новичок не судите строго.

Comment: я не специалист по C#, но не должна ли фигурная скобка быть закрыта в FixedUpdate?

Comment: @rg4s А, точно, `OnCollisionEnter` получается описана внутри `FixedUpdate`, поэтому и не работает. Вообще очень неаккуратно отформатированный код.

Comment: Так еще и в FixedUpdate() используется deltaTime вместо fixedDeltaTime...

Comment: @Александр Даниловский, это одно и то же, если используется в FixedUpdate.

Comment: @Qwer нет, совершенно не одно и то же

Comment: @Александр Даниловский, из [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html): _"When this is called from inside MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate, it returns Time.fixedDeltaTime"_.

Comment: @Qwer признаю свою неправоту. Но это зависит от версии Юнити. И, ИМХО, это странное решение со стороны юнитеков возвращать разное значение в зависимости от точки вызова...

Comment: А не лучше ли будет вместо того что бы обнулять поворот обнулить силу поворота или использовать это вместе

Comment: @Александр Даниловский, опускать порог вхождения - это политика компании. Слишком много "разработчиков" писали deltaTime вместо fixedDeltaTime.